# How to find specific holiday date that varies by year in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query for dates that come the week before Labor Day. Labor Day is a US federal holiday on the first Monday of every September. I'm trying to select labor day and the full week before labor day. I'm somewhat close with this sort of query

```
select * from `bigquery-public-data.ghcn_d.ghcnd_1991` 

where extract(month from date) = 9 
and extract(dayofweek from date) = 2  
and extract(week from date) = 36
```

But it's not always the 36th week, sometimes its the 35th (so the query above is wrong).

I'm guessing I'll have to do a date subtraction in order to get the full week before labor day...but for now I just need help finding how to query the first Monday of every September.

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach:

```
select    t.*
from      `bigquery-public-data.ghcn_d.ghcnd_1991` t
     join (
            select    format_date('%Y%m',date) as yr_mo,
                      date_sub(min(date), interval 1 week)  as week_before,
                      min(date) as first_monday
            from      `bigquery-public-data.ghcn_d.ghcnd_1991`   v
            where     extract(dayofweek from date) = 2 
                  and extract(month from date) = 9
            group by  format_date('%Y%m',date)
          ) v
       on t.date between v.week_before and v.first_monday;
```

This presumes you want all rows of the table where the date is Labor Day or within the week leading to Labor Day.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is the first Monday of September you can perform a `MIN` on date within a CTE, or a subquery, to get Labor Day and the prior week:

```
WITH labor_day as (
  select MIN(date) date
  from `bigquery-public-data.ghcn_d.ghcnd_1991` 
  where extract(month from date) = 9 
  and extract(dayofweek from date) = 2  
)

SELECT distinct ghcnd.date
FROM `bigquery-public-data.ghcn_d.ghcnd_1991` ghcnd
INNER JOIN labor_day 
 on ghcnd.date between labor_day.date-7 and labor_day.date
```